# Does Qt have a balloon widget (popup pointing to its parent)?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui

Sorry for the lame question and for not really knowing the name of the widget depicted bellow.

I looked around in the Qt examples and couldn't find anything similar. Any hints on how to implement this or knowledge of someone that released this kind of widget?

Ideally I would like to have that widget "pointing" to `QAction` (or `QWidgetActon` for that matter) and regular buttons (QPush & Tool).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such widget in Qt, but you can create your own custom shaped one.

Check the [Shaped Clock Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-widgets-shapedclock-example.html) and [QWidget::setMask()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#setMask-1) method.